# Android: SwipeRefreshLayout not working on match_parent

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

The problem is: when SwipeRefreshLayout have android:layout_height="match_parent" - nothing is showed on layout, when its set on something like 200dp it shows listview and refresh works. Listview is populated by custom adapter with rest api.

[match_parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGLVW.png)

[200dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjAUJ.png)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Swipelayout_for_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.darek.playerandroid.PlaylistsFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvPlaylists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"></ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Update with content_dashboard xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.darek.playerandroid.Dashboard"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

app_bar_dashboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.darek.playerandroid.Dashboard">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

playlist_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nosub"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgSub"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPlaylistName"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Playlist name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlaylistName"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make it wrap_content

Comment: do it using layout_weight property.

Comment: wrap_content - still nothing,

Comment: layout_weight - no its not, where should i try with that one?

Comment: @MeghaManiar nope why `layout_weight `

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/normal_space_between_view_in_home"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/normal_space_between_view_in_home"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".activities.DashboardActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_data_available"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the fragment:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
```

Comment: It's just for your reference. Please make necessary changes.

Comment: im not familiar with recyclerview, can i use list_item.xml and adapter used for listview?

Comment: yes. Instead of recyclerView use Listview. I am updating above code accordingly

Comment: unfortunately, still nothing :( < setting height to 200dp displays it. thats so wierd

Comment: Iv made also version with recycler view, still nothing shows on match_parent, 200 or so shows list of items :(